# how to programmatically remove an attribute completely in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, e4x

I am experimenting with e4x. I could programmatically add an attribute to an Xml by doing something like this :

```
xml.@name = 'jerry';
```

now i have added a name attribute to it programmatically because even though the xml had no attribute called name, after the statement above, it automatically has one now. 
My difficulty now is how do i , as well, remove the name attribute i have inserted programmatically again?

Answer (score 3):

Use following operator:

```
delete xml.@name;
```